# How do I display unique database values from a column to avoid duplicates using LINQ with Razor? Display data in a textbox form

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0, razor-pages

I have 2 issues, the first is I'm trying to avoid duplicate values and display SELECT DISTINCT Names in a column as shown in the image, there are 2 rows with the name Rob, I only want to display 1 since both rows have the same name.

My other issue is I'm trying to fill the textbox with the column information from the selected name that is clicked on

index.cshtml

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{ ViewData["Title"] = "Index"; }

<form method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBox("TxtDepartment")
            </td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" id="DepartmentSearch">Search</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
<br />

<table>
    <tr>
        <td><div id="DepartmentResult"></div></td>&nbsp;
        <td><div id="EmployeeResult"></div></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<form method="post">
    <label>Department Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="DeptName" />
    <label>Photo File Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="NameResult" />
</form>

@section Scripts {
    <script>
        $("#DepartmentSearch").click(function()
        {
            $.ajax(
            {
                url: "/Index?handler=DisplayDepartment",
                type: "POST",
                data: { value: $("#TxtDepartment").val() },
                headers: { RequestVerificationToken: $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() },
                success: function(data) { $("#DepartmentResult").html(data); }
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

index.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using PracticeApp.Models;
using System.Linq;

namespace PracticeApp.Pages
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        public CompanyContext _context;

        public IndexModel(CompanyContext context) { _context = context; }

        public PartialViewResult OnGetDisplayDepartment(int value)
        {
            return Partial("_DisplayDepartmentPartial", _context.Departments.Where(x => x.DepartmentId == value).ToList());
        }

        public PartialViewResult OnGetDisplayEmployee(string value)
        {
            return Partial("_DisplayEmployeePartial", _context.Employees.Where(x => x.DepartmentName == value).ToList());
        }

        public PartialViewResult OnGetDisplayInfo(string value)
        {
            return Partial("_DisplayEmployeePartial", _context.Employees.Where(x => x.EmployeeName == value).ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

_DisplayDepartmentPartial.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<Models.Department>

@if (Model.Count() != 0)
 {
    <table style="border: 1px solid black">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="2" style="border: 1px solid black; text-align: center;">Department Results</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" style="border: 1px solid black; font-weight: bold;">
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.DepartmentName)
                </td>
            </tr>

            @foreach (Models.Department item in Model)
             {
                <tr>
                    <td id="TxtEmployee" align="center" style="border: 1px solid black;">
                        <a id="EmployeeSearch" href="javascript:aa()">@item.DepartmentName</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
             }
        </tbody>
    </table>
 }
else
{
    <p>No data</p>
}

<script>
    $("#EmployeeSearch").click(function()
    {
        $.ajax(
        {
            url: "Index?handler=DisplayEmployee",
            type: "POST",
            data: { value: $("#EmployeeSearch").text() },
            headers: { RequestVerificationToken: $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() },
            success: function(data) { $("#EmployeeResult").html(data); }
        });
    });
</script>
```

_DisplayEmployeePartial.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<Models.Employee>

@if (Model.Count() != 0)
 {
    <table style="border: 1px solid black">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="2" style="border: 1px solid black; text-align: center;">Employee Results</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" style="border: 1px solid black; font-weight: bold;">
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.EmployeeName)
                </td>
            </tr>

            @foreach (Models.Employee item in Model)
             {
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" style="border: 1px solid black;">
                        <a id="PopulateNameData" href="javascript:aa()">@item.EmployeeName</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
             }
        </tbody>
    </table>
 }
else
{
    <p>No data</p>
}

<script>
    $("#PopulateNameData").click(function()
    {
        $.ajax(
        {
            url: "Index?handler=DisplayEmployee",
            type: "POST",
            data: { value: $("#PopulateNameData").text() },
            headers: { RequestVerificationToken: $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() },
            success: function(data) { $("#NameResult").html(data); }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Employee Model

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace PracticeApp.Models
{
    public partial class Employee
    {
        [Display(Name = "Employee ID")] public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Department ID")] public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Name")] public string EmployeeName { get; set; } = null!;
        public string DepartmentName { get; set; } = null!;
        public DateTime DateofJoining { get; set; }
        public string PhotoFileName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: [Distinct](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct)?

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT SQL query but using LINQ like in my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your linq like below:

```
public PartialViewResult OnGetDisplayEmployee(string value)
{
    return Partial("_DisplayEmployeePartial", _context.Employees.Where(x => x.DepartmentName == value).GroupBy(x=>x.EmployeeName).Select(x => x.First()).ToList());
}
```

Comment: Ty @Rena, you have come through once again for me, shame that Stack doesn't have contact information for it's users

Were you able to see the second part to my question regarding the input textboxes?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
_context.Employees
.Where(x => x.DepartmentName == value)
.Distinct()
.ToList());
```

Or you can try specifying the fields:

```
_context.Employees
.Where(x => x.DepartmentName == value)
.Select(x => new {
  EmployeeId = x.EmployeeId,
  EmployeeName = x.EmployeeName 
 })
.Distinct()
.ToList());
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=net-7.0

Comment: yes I did actually and it didn't work

Comment: I think it needs to be done in the EmployeePartial somewhere just can't figure it out